# Redirrect from to JSP to @RequestParam

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

So I'm having this code in a JSP file:

```
<form action="/demo/quests/view?questId=${m.id}" >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >See quest</button>
</form
```

My method has this definition:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayQuest(@RequestParam(value = "questId") String questId, Model model){}
```

The problem is that my form is redirrecting to `quests/view?`
How can I make it redirrect to `quests/view?questId=asdasdasd`

**Using @requestParam is a must, because with @PathVariable I get a weird bug

Answer (score 0):

Your method definition is ok but you should use your form submission as :

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/demo/quests/view">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="questId" 
    name="questId" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >See quest</button>
</form
```

`@RequestParam` handles that there is a parameter with name `questId` which is described at your `@RequestParam(value = "questId")` method signature. You can check an exact example from my github repo.

***Form Sample:***   [modalAuthor.jsp#form](https://github.com/muzir/azorka.web/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/util/modalAuthor.jsp)

***Handler Method Sample*** [AuthorController#authorPost](https://github.com/muzir/azorka.web/blob/master/src/main/java/com/azorka/controller/AuthorController.java)

Answer (score 0):

> Replace

```
 <form action="/demo/quests/view?questId=${m.id}" >
```

> with

```
<form action="view?questId=${m.id}" >
```

Comment: not working :)
My temporary solution is to make a simple redirrect with javascript

Comment: sorry, but it's irrelevant anyway...The button action is the problem.
If I'm manually entering .../demo/quest/view?questId=asdasdasd  , it's working